# Need good and thin heat conductor without electrical conduction

Tags: heat, heat-protection, overheat

I have a 3D printer with magnetic hot plate and steel sheets. One side of the sheet is uncovered (bare metal) and with the usage the sheet scraped some parts of the heatbed PCB mask resulting in exposed copper traces. The sheet started to touch those traces and short-circuit everything so more mask got burned and exposed. The base is still usable and works fine with full covered sheets but the problem continues.

I also tried to repair and apply green solder mask but once a sheet is touched it got scraped. Sheets are thin and sharp... Magnets are too powerful to apply or take sheet vertically so as a sheet is inserted at an angle it scrapes the PCB.

My question is, what's the best material I can use to fix this and apply a electrical isolator between bed and sheet? It must be thin so that the magnet still grabs the sheet and a good heat conductor but without electrical conduction. I'm OK with tape if that will do.

PS: I most use mostly 60°C and 90°C at heat bed, but 115°C is occasionally used, so material must survive that temperature.

In home i have krypton tape and blue painters type, don't know if that will do for what i need.

Comment: I would use Kapton tape. Apply it edge-to-edge so that there are both no gaps and no overlap. Kapton tape is fairly robust and is easily replaced when it gets damaged.

Comment: You should also file or sand the edges of the steel plates so there no sharp edges. In other words, get rid of the sharp burr that is causing the damage to the heated bed coating.

Comment: You can get 0.005" thick glass laminate. Not sure if that will work for you. Basically the same substrate PCBs are made of.

Comment: @DwayneReid, ok will do that, the Kapton is also used to protect against direct heat, will that drop me some degrees at top sheet? The sheet edges are not cutting, i can rub my skin there without cut, but sheets are thin and by take and put the sheet so many times it wear the mask, but i should do that too.

Comment: @DKNguyen glass have the risk of break and need to be glued or fixed anyway, so it can do more trouble...

Comment: @TiagoConceição It's glass cloth in an epoxy matrix, not a sheet of glass. It's a film that can bend and comes delivered on a roll like a poster. Think of a thin film made of the same "plastic" that a printed circuit board is made of.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ah ok, can provide any ebay link? I'm not finding it by fiber glass or laminated glass under search, can only find thick glass planes

Comment: @TiagoConceição The technical name for the material is G-10 or FR-4. It's definiately not laminated glass (which is an actual sheet of glass with a reinforcing film). It's a glass laminate. Two different things. I don't know where else you can get it but this is one place: https://store.acpsales.com/products/2342/fiberglass-sheets-natural

Comment: A kapton sheet might be more abrasion resistant and also available much thinner. But I think kapton is actually more expensive.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation, i will try kypton type first as i already have it here in large width, hope it don't take much heat transfer out of sheet. regards

Comment: Just applied the tape, i take temperature reference before and after, it seens with tape the heat is even better distributed and more close to target (60) at last sheet, from 54ºc (before) to 58ºc (after) at center and after a while 60ºc!, very good.
I left a tape margin at edges, should i trim or leave them?